# HierarchicalDataTemplate for Windows 8 xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Is it possible to bind Hierarchical Data source in Windows 8? Assume if I created my own HeaderedItems Control. I am a XAML user.

Comment: Seems toolkit has one,
http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/